# Why is xcode not letting me use my static variable?

Tags: c++

I'm pretty sure I'm making some stupid mistake.
Can't seem to find it, and no good results when googling it either.

When I run my SDL project I get these errors :

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "Input::evnt", referenced
>   from:
>         Input::ProcessInput() in Input.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

I know these are the lines that are causing the error :

```
switch (evnt->type)
{
    case SDL_KEYDOWN:
        std::cout << "Key pressed" << std::endl;
        break;

}
```

I know it's not the "contains" of the while loop, but the while loop itself.

This is what my evnt variable looks like :

```
static SDL_Event* evnt;
```

---

Not sure what I'm doing wrong....

Answer (score 1):

You need to both define and declare static variables. I'm assuming that you declared your `SDL_Event*` variable in a header file, inside a class declaration or something similar. That's only half the work of adding a static variable. You need to also define it, such as `static SDL_Event* MyClass::event`. Anyways, you probably don't need to make the event `static`. It should work fine just either as a normal class member or even a local variable.

Comment: But then it gives me another error saying that it needs to be static. lol Though I'm not sure what you mean by define. In my constructor I do : evnt = new SDL_Event(); which doesn't work. :/

Comment: Yeah. You're going to need to find a basic C++ tutorial.